# Explanation needed on Deferred lights

Tags: deferred, light

I have implemented a simple deferred shading engine in opengl but now im stuck on the point lights part.

I have searched evry where and i simply cant find a good explanation on how the point lights work.

First why do they have to be draw as a mesh?

Cant i simply pass the values ot the vertex shader and run a loop for all the lights that i have passed?

i mean for the direcitonal light you just have to do a simpel phong on shading on every pixel...

I guess im just looking for a nice simple explanation on how the point lights work in deferred  shading, if some one could explain it to me or point me in the right direction it would be much apreciated.

thanks.